# Blue ocean can't re-run with updated Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The Blue Ocean interface doesn't have the option to build with the latest version of the Jenkinsfile i.e. by doing a git pull and then running the pipeline. It only has the option to re-run the existing commit which is kinda useless when you're developing the pipeline?

It's something so obvious that it's my interpretation that must be off. There appears to be a straightforward way to do this without having to revert to the classic interface and trigger a build that way.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Right now I have to keep two tabs open. One is the classical view which allows me to 'Build with Parameters' which does a git pull. The second is the blue ocean url within which I have to find the build Id and increment by 1 after kicking off the build in the classical view.